# Does the lack of some features from UA on XGTE means that they weren't approved by WotC?

Tags: dnd-5e, unearthed-arcana

Considering that Xanathar's Guide to Everything is mostly a compendium of the Unearthed Arcana making everything that went into it oficial, can we say that the things that were left out weren't approved on the play test?

I'm asking this because of the note on page 4 of XGTE:

> Much of the material in this book originally appeared in Unearthed
>   Arcana, a series of online articles we publish to explore rules that
>   might ofificially become part of the game. Some Unearthed Arcana
>   offerings don’t end up resonating with fans and are set aside for the
>   time being.
>
> The Unearthed Arcana material that inspired the options in
>   the following chapters was well received and, thanks to feedback from
>   thousands of you, has been refined into the official forms presented
>   here.

Are things like the Tunnel Fighter fighting style and the multiples feats unapproved on the play test?

Comment: What do you mean by "weren't approved"? Weren't approved by the community, or by WotC, or what?

Comment: WotC decides what's oficial so it's them.

Comment: Well, you obviously already know that things from UA that aren't in XGtE aren't official, so what are you asking, then?

Comment: I'm asking if they were discarded/deemed unbalanced.

Comment: I'm basicaly asking if there's any pronunciation from WotC/Jeremy Crawford about of what was left out of XGTE.

Comment: I still don't get it--why is that quote unsatisfactory? What more are you looking for?

Comment: "set aside for the time being" seems extremely clear.

Comment: Please [edit] to clarify. Comments are useful, but we have to have to have the question itself be in a shape ready to be answered, or we'll just see answers written by people who haven't read the comments, misunderstood the comments, and generally result in answers not answering what you think you're asking. (I would normally take these comments and do the edit myself, but I'm honestly not sure I'm 100% clear on what the clarifications actually amount to, and so I'm punting to the person ultimately responsible for question quality: the author.)

Answer (score 5):

First, to the core point: Yes, content that was in UA but did not make it into an official release such as *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* is not 'official', at least in the sense of its legality in Adventurer's League and/or its status as 'officially released'. They are still in 'draft form', as the foreword at the beginning of all (recent) UA articles indicate.

Mike Mearls had [an interview on Nerdarchy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ld6bS3ptYws&t=45m15s) that spoke to some details of what this means. Specifically mentioned around 45m15s, there was something of a line around ~70% playtester approval as to what did or did not make the cut into Xanathar's release (and even the content that was approved got some amount of further revision), and the stuff that didn't make the cut *may* go back to the drawing board for a future UA release.

As such, there's the possibility of UA that wasn't released to either be permanently cut or to be seen again in the future with more changes (and I don't believe much if any public commentary has been made on specific details on any given such UA).